# csrf protection only works on some post requests

Tags: html, node.js, csrf

I will be posting a part of what works and doesnt work.
The first part is a working part

```
app.get('/createblogpost', function(request, response){

if(request.cookies.sessionid == request.session.id){
    response.render("createblogpost.hbs", {layout:'mainlogedin.hbs', token:request.csrfToken()})
}else{
    response.render("createblogpost.hbs", {token:request.csrfToken()})
}
})
<form method="POST" action="/addblog">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="headline">Headline</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="headline" name="headline" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="textarea">Content</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="10" required></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{token}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Create</button>
</form>
```

this part doesnt work and it looks about the same.

```
app.get('/uploadimage', function(request, response){

if(request.cookies.sessionid == request.session.id){
    response.render("uploadimage.hbs", {layout:'mainlogedin.hbs', token:request.csrfToken()})
}else{
    response.render("uploadimage.hbs", {token:request.csrfToken()})
}
})

<form method="POST" action="/addimage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="headline">Headline</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="headline" name="headline" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image" required>Choose a image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image" value="upload image" required accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{token}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Create</button>
</form>
```

Also the login and logout forms work fine and some other more forms dont work. I have no idea whats going on.
I can add that when i look at the _csrf cookie the value doesnt change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but I'm a bit unsure what the issue was. I added

```
app.get('/uploadimage', csrfProtection, function(request, response)
```

Moved the csrf up a bit in the code so it was called before everything else, and any other thing I could think of and that I read on different post. The code I posted is still the same. I did need a token in one of my post requests but I just sent the youngest token to that post request and passed it to the render there too.